# Parsing images from JSON string and showing them in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have found this codepen here : [LINK](http://codepen.io/Navedkhan012/pen/oLwYEr) and I am trying to replicate it in an .HTML file where I will be getting the data from a JSON file.

So, the first part of what I am trying to do was successful. I parsed the data from the JSON string as shown below:
[image]

The only thing I cannot make work is the slider. Even if I load exactly the same script files as they appear in the codepen, I am getting an error. When I am saving everything in an HTML file I am getting the following:

[image]

It does not work even if I used this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
            ticker: true,
            tickerSpeed:2000,
            tickerHover: true
    });
});
```

The snippet is shown below :

```js
$(function() {
   
    var unformatted = {"headers":["Image"],"rows": [["http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/1.jpg"],["http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/2.jpg"]]};
    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < unformatted.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = unformatted.rows[i];

        data.push({
            Image: row[0]
        });
    }
            var tt = $('<ul id="slider">');;
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                tt.append('<li><a href="#"><img src="' + val.Image + '"/></a></li>');
                $(".slider-container").append(tt);
            });

        });
```

```css
#slider {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px
}

.slider-container { 
 background:#222; 
 width:845px; 
 height:150px; 
 padding:20px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px; 
}

#slider img { 
 width:200px; 
 height:125px; 
 margin:0px; 
 display:inline-block  
}

#slider li {
 width:210px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wpandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/jquery.bxSlider.js"></script>


<div class="slider-container"></div>


<script>
       $('#slider').bxSlider({
      ticker: true,
      tickerSpeed:2000,
   tickerHover: true
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Try waiting for the document to be loaded: `$(document).ready(function() { $("#slider").bxSlider({});});`

Comment: I did try that with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your `jquery.bxSlider.js` is not getting loaded is throwing mixed content error.

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS
>   connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets,
>   scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Try adding a local copy of the js and reference the local copy on your server in your html.

Remove the Initialization of the slider  from the script tag an put it at the end of the js file.

You were using script tag to load the bxSlider which was executed before you have dynamically added the ul and li's.

As shown in the snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(function() {

  var unformatted = {
    "headers": ["Image"],
    "rows": [
      ["http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/1.jpg"],
      ["http://www.webdesignandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/logos/2.jpg"]
    ]
  };
  var data = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < unformatted.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = unformatted.rows[i];

    data.push({
      Image: row[0]
    });
  }
  var tt = $('<ul id="slider">');;
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    tt.append('<li><a href="#"><img src="' + val.Image + '"/></a></li>');
    $(".slider-container").append(tt);
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider').bxSlider({
    ticker: true,
    tickerSpeed: 2000,
    tickerHover: true
  });
});
```

```css
/* 
 jQuery Logo Slider Ticker 
 by http://webdesignandsuch.com
 build with code from http://bxslider.com
*/


#slider {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px
}

.slider-container { 
 background:#222; 
 width:845px; 
 height:150px; 
 padding:20px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px; 
}

#slider img { 
 width:200px; 
 height:125px; 
 margin:0px; 
 display:inline-block  
}

#slider li {
 width:210px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
/**
 * jQuery bxSlider v3.0
 * http://bxslider.com
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Steven Wanderski
 * http://bxcreative.com
 *
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 */
(function(a){a.fn.bxSlider=function(b){function Z(b,c,d,e){var f=[];var g=d;var h=false;if(e=="backward"){b=a.makeArray(b);b.reverse()}while(g>0){a.each(b,function(b,d){if(g>0){if(!h){if(b==c){h=true;f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{f.push(a(this).clone());g--}}else{return false}})}return f}function Y(){var a=i.outerHeight()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function X(){var a=i.outerWidth()*b.displaySlideQty;return a}function W(b,c){if(c=="left"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().left}else if(c=="top"){var d=a(".pager",h).eq(b).position().top}return d}function V(){if(!b.infiniteLoop&&b.hideControlOnEnd){if(x==F){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-prev",h).show()}if(x==G){a(".bx-next",h).hide()}else{a(".bx-next",h).show()}}}function U(c,e,f,g){p=a('<a href="" class="bx-start"></a>');if(c=="text"){r=e}else{r='<img src="source/'+e+'" />'}if(f=="text"){s=g}else{s='<img src="source/'+g+'" />'}if(b.autoControlsSelector){a(b.autoControlsSelector).append(p)}else{h.append('<div class="bx-auto"></div>');a(".bx-auto",h).html(p)}p.click(function(){if(b.ticker){if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopTicker()}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startTicker()}}else{if(a(this).hasClass("stop")){d.stopShow(true)}else if(a(this).hasClass("start")){d.startShow(true)}}return false})}function T(){var c=a("img",g.eq(x)).attr("title");if(c!=""){if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html(c)}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html(c)}}else{if(b.captionsSelector){a(b.captionsSelector).html("� ")}else{a(".bx-captions",h).html("� ")}}}function S(c){var e=g.length;if(b.moveSlideQty>1){if(g.length%b.moveSlideQty!=0){e=Math.ceil(g.length/b.moveSlideQty)}else{e=g.length/b.moveSlideQty}}var f="";if(b.buildPager){for(var i=0;i<e;i++){f+=b.buildPager(i,g.eq(i*b.moveSlideQty))}}else if(c=="full"){for(var i=1;i<=e;i++){f+='<a href="" class="pager-link pager-'+i+'">'+i+"</a>"}}else if(c=="short"){f='<span class="bx-pager-current">'+(b.startingSlide+1)+"</span> "+b.pagerShortSeparator+' <span class="bx-pager-total">'+g.length+"</span>"}if(b.pagerSelector){a(b.pagerSelector).append(f);n=a(b.pagerSelector)}else{var j=a('<div class="bx-pager"></div>');j.append(f);if(b.pagerLocation=="top"){h.prepend(j)}else if(b.pagerLocation=="bottom"){h.append(j)}n=a(".bx-pager",h)}n.children().click(function(){if(b.pagerType=="full"){var a=n.children().index(this);if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a*=b.moveSlideQty}d.goToSlide(a)}return false})}function R(c,e,f,g){var i=a('<a href="" class="bx-next"></a>');var j=a('<a href="" class="bx-prev"></a>');if(c=="text"){i.html(e)}else{i.html('<img src="source/'+e+'" />')}if(f=="text"){j.html(g)}else{j.html('<img src="source/'+g+'" />')}if(b.prevSelector){a(b.prevSelector).append(j)}else{h.append(j)}if(b.nextSelector){a(b.nextSelector).append(i)}else{h.append(i)}i.click(function(){d.goToNextSlide();return false});j.click(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide();return false})}function Q(c){if(b.pagerType=="full"&&b.pager){a("a",n).removeClass(b.pagerActiveClass);a("a",n).eq(c).addClass(b.pagerActiveClass)}else if(b.pagerType=="short"&&b.pager){a(".bx-pager-current",n).html(x+1)}}function P(){g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(b.speed,0).css("zIndex",98);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99).fadeTo(b.speed,1,function(){E=false;if(jQuery.browser.msie){g.eq(x).get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}function O(){e.hover(function(){if(t){d.stopTicker(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startTicker(false)}})}function N(){h.find(".bx-window").hover(function(){if(t){d.stopShow(false)}},function(){if(t){d.startShow(false)}})}function M(){if(b.startImage!=""){startContent=b.startImage;startType="image"}else{startContent=b.startText;startType="text"}if(b.stopImage!=""){stopContent=b.stopImage;stopType="image"}else{stopContent=b.stopText;stopType="text"}U(startType,startContent,stopType,stopContent)}function L(a,c,d){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({left:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({left:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("left",a);L(a,A,b.tickerSpeed)})}}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){e.animate({top:"-="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){e.animate({top:"+="+c+"px"},d,"linear",function(){e.css("top",a);L(a,B,b.tickerSpeed)})}}}function K(){if(b.auto){if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){x+=b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){x-=b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}}d.goToSlide(x,false)},b.pause)}}else{if(b.autoDirection=="next"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToNextSlide(false)},b.pause)}else if(b.autoDirection=="prev"){o=setInterval(function(){d.goToPreviousSlide(false)},b.pause)}}}else if(b.ticker){b.tickerSpeed*=10;a(".pager",h).each(function(b){A+=a(this).width();B+=a(this).height()});if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="horizontal"){e.css("left","-"+(A+y)+"px")}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"&&b.mode=="vertical"){e.css("top","-"+(B+z)+"px")}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){C=parseInt(e.css("left"));L(C,A,b.tickerSpeed)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){D=parseInt(e.css("top"));L(D,B,b.tickerSpeed)}if(b.tickerHover){O()}}}function J(){if(b.nextImage!=""){nextContent=b.nextImage;nextType="image"}else{nextContent=b.nextText;nextType="text"}if(b.prevImage!=""){prevContent=b.prevImage;prevType="image"}else{prevContent=b.prevText;prevType="text"}R(nextType,nextContent,prevType,prevContent)}function I(){if(b.mode=="horizontal"||b.mode=="vertical"){var c=Z(g,0,b.moveSlideQty,"backward");a.each(c,function(b){e.prepend(a(this))});var d=g.length+b.moveSlideQty-1;var f=g.length-b.displaySlideQty;var h=d-f;var i=Z(g,0,h,"forward");if(b.infiniteLoop){a.each(i,function(b){e.append(a(this))})}}}function H(){I(b.startingSlide);if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+l+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:'+l+'px;"></div>').css({width:"999999px",position:"relative",left:"-"+y+"px"});e.children().css({width:j,"float":"left",listStyle:"none"});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="width:'+v+"px; height:"+m+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>').css({height:"999999px",position:"relative",top:"-"+z+"px"});e.children().css({listStyle:"none",height:w});h=e.parent().parent();g.addClass("pager")}else if(b.mode=="fade"){e.wrap('<div class="'+b.wrapperClass+'" style="width:'+v+'px; position:relative;"></div>').wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="height:'+w+"px; width:"+v+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>');e.children().css({listStyle:"none",position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,zIndex:98});h=e.parent().parent();g.not(":eq("+x+")").fadeTo(0,0);g.eq(x).css("zIndex",99)}if(b.captions&&b.captionsSelector==null){h.append('<div class="bx-captions"></div>')}}var c={mode:"horizontal",infiniteLoop:true,hideControlOnEnd:false,controls:true,speed:500,easing:"swing",pager:false,pagerSelector:null,pagerType:"full",pagerLocation:"bottom",pagerShortSeparator:"/",pagerActiveClass:"pager-active",nextText:"next",nextImage:"",nextSelector:null,prevText:"prev",prevImage:"",prevSelector:null,captions:false,captionsSelector:null,auto:false,autoDirection:"next",autoControls:false,autoControlsSelector:null,autoStart:true,autoHover:false,autoDelay:0,pause:3e3,startText:"start",startImage:"",stopText:"stop",stopImage:"",ticker:false,tickerSpeed:5e3,tickerDirection:"next",tickerHover:false,wrapperClass:"bx-wrapper",startingSlide:0,displaySlideQty:4,moveSlideQty:1,randomStart:false,onBeforeSlide:function(){},onAfterSlide:function(){},onLastSlide:function(){},onFirstSlide:function(){},onNextSlide:function(){},onPrevSlide:function(){},buildPager:null};var b=a.extend(c,b);var d=this;var e="";var f="";var g="";var h="";var i="";var j="";var k="";var l="";var m="";var n="";var o="";var p="";var q="";var r="";var s="";var t=true;var u=false;var v=0;var w=0;var x=0;var y=0;var z=0;var A=0;var B=0;var C=0;var D=0;var E=false;var F=0;var G=g.length-1;this.goToSlide=function(a,c){if(!E){E=true;x=a;b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}slide=a;if(slide==F){b.onFirstSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(slide==G){b.onLastSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))}if(b.mode=="horizontal"){e.animate({left:"-"+W(slide,"left")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){e.animate({top:"-"+W(slide,"top")+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}V();if(b.moveSlideQty>1){a=Math.floor(a/b.moveSlideQty)}Q(a);T()}};this.goToNextSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x<=G){V();b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}else{x-=b.moveSlideQty}}}else{if(!E){E=true;var c=false;x=x+b.moveSlideQty;if(x>G){x=x%g.length;c=true}b.onNextSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var f=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"-="+f+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var h=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"-="+h+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(c){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToPreviousSlide=function(c){if(typeof c=="undefined"){var c=true}if(c){if(b.auto){d.stopShow(true)}}if(!b.infiniteLoop){if(!E){var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){x=0;if(b.hideControlOnEnd){a(".bx-prev",h).hide()}}V();b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));d.goToSlide(x)}}else{if(!E){E=true;var f=false;x=x-b.moveSlideQty;if(x<0){negativeOffset=x%g.length;if(negativeOffset==0){x=0}else{x=g.length+negativeOffset}f=true}b.onPrevSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));b.onBeforeSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x));if(b.mode=="horizontal"){var i=b.moveSlideQty*k;e.animate({left:"+="+i+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("left","-"+W(x,"left")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){var j=b.moveSlideQty*w;e.animate({top:"+="+j+"px"},b.speed,b.easing,function(){E=false;if(f){e.css("top","-"+W(x,"top")+"px")}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))})}else if(b.mode=="fade"){P()}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}T()}}};this.goToFirstSlide=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(F,a)};this.goToLastSlide=function(){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}d.goToSlide(G,a)};this.getCurrentSlide=function(){return x};this.getSlideCount=function(){return g.length};this.stopShow=function(a){clearInterval(o);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startShow=function(a){if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}K();if(a&&b.autoControls){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}};this.stopTicker=function(a){e.stop();if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(r).removeClass("stop").addClass("start");t=false}};this.startTicker=function(a){if(b.mode=="horizontal"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var c=parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=A+c+g.eq(0).width()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var c=-parseInt(e.css("left"));var d=c-g.eq(0).width()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/A;L(C,d,f)}else if(b.mode=="vertical"){if(b.tickerDirection=="next"){var h=parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=B+h+g.eq(0).height()}else if(b.tickerDirection=="prev"){var h=-parseInt(e.css("top"));var d=h-g.eq(0).height()}var f=d*b.tickerSpeed/B;L(D,d,f);if(typeof a=="undefined"){var a=true}if(a&&b.ticker){p.html(s).removeClass("start").addClass("stop");t=true}}};this.initShow=function(){e=a(this);f=e.clone();g=e.children();h="";i=e.children(":first");j=i.width();v=0;k=i.outerWidth();w=0;l=X();m=Y();E=false;n="";x=0;y=0;z=0;o="";p="";q="";r="";s="";t=true;u=false;A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0;F=0;G=g.length-1;g.each(function(b){if(a(this).outerHeight()>w){w=a(this).outerHeight()}if(a(this).outerWidth()>v){v=a(this).outerWidth()}});if(b.randomStart){var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length);x=c;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+c);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+c)}else{x=b.startingSlide;y=k*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide);z=w*(b.moveSlideQty+b.startingSlide)}H();if(b.pager&&!b.ticker){if(b.pagerType=="full"){S("full")}else if(b.pagerType=="short"){S("short")}}if(b.controls&&!b.ticker){J()}if(b.auto||b.ticker){if(b.autoControls){M()}if(b.autoStart){setTimeout(function(){d.startShow(true)},b.autoDelay)}else{d.stopShow(true)}if(b.autoHover&&!b.ticker){N()}}if(b.moveSlideQty>1){Q(Math.ceil(x/b.moveSlideQty))}else{Q(x)}V();if(b.captions){T()}b.onAfterSlide(x,g.length,g.eq(x))};this.destroyShow=function(){clearInterval(o);a(".bx-next, .bx-prev, .bx-pager, .bx-auto",h).remove();e.unwrap().unwrap().removeAttr("style");e.children().removeAttr("style").not(".pager").remove();g.removeClass("pager")};this.reloadShow=function(){d.destroyShow();d.initShow()};this.each(function(){if(a(this).children().length>0){d.initShow()}});return this};jQuery.fx.prototype.cur=function(){if(this.elem[this.prop]!=null&&(!this.elem.style||this.elem.style[this.prop]==null)){return this.elem[this.prop]}var a=parseFloat(jQuery.css(this.elem,this.prop));return a}})(jQuery)
</script>


<div class="slider-container"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of loading the file (library), I pasted the raw script in the script tags and I got the same error.

Comment: It worked because of the change of the jquery version that was loaded in the header. You used the 2.1.1 That was the only change I made and it now works. Interesting. How is it supposed to work in codepen then?

Comment: The problem was that some of the content was loading via `http` and the other via `https`.

Comment: No, its not the jquery problem. You were using script tag to load the bxSlider which was executed before you have  dynamically added the ul and li's

Comment: Another problem was using mixed content as the snippets in stack overflow is in https and you were referencing the slider js over http.